# CSS Slider: with div

Tags: html, css, slider

i am trying to make a slider with div, but all the div stick together with the animation. I mean, it should appear one by one.

I have this:

```
<div class="mh-footer-menu" id="menu-second_nav">
   <div class="slider">
      <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/4da7ae8be51cdc062177ceaa1b8eba71-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="quienes-somos" width="150" height="150">
      <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=371">Quienes somos</a> 
   </div>
   <div class="slider">
       <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/MapaInternet-2015-150x150.png" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="MapaInternet-2015" width="150" height="150">
       <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=369">Integrantes</a>
  </div>
```

And this:

```
@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}

div#menu-second_nav {
    background-color: #e64946; 
    height: 80%; 
    width: auto;
    padding: 2%;
}

div#menu-second_nav { overflow: hidden; }
div#menu-second_nav div.slider { width: 20%; float: left; }
div#menu-second_nav div.slider { 
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  /*margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;*/
  animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
}

div#menu-second_nav div.slider a {
   color: #000000;
   margin-left: 2%;
}

div#menu-second_nav div.slider a:hover { 
    color: #ffffff; 
}

div#menu-second_nav div.slider img {
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

What can i do, so the 2 div's appear one by one. Right now it is show like this:
[print Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrBj1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not just use something like nivo slider. its easy to use and customize.

https://github.com/gilbitron/Nivo-Slider